# Java Swing Timer only runs once

Tags: java, swing, timer

Can anyone tell me why does this timer run only once?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimerTest implements ActionListener{

    private Robot r;
    private Timer t;
    private int i;

    public TimerTest(){     
        i = 0;  
        try {
            r = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        t = new Timer(1000, this);  
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.start();  
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        new TimerTest();        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        i++;
        System.out.println("Action..." + i);        
    }
```

The funny thing is that, if I decrease the delay in the Timer to just 100, it works as expected. And what's even funnier is that if I delete the code in which I initialize the Robot, it doesn't work at all, the program terminates as soon as I run it.

I've tried this on Windows 7 and on Ubuntu (although on Ubuntu I couldn't use the Robot at all, since I get an exception. Something related to rights, maybe).

Comment: What is the content of Robot?

Comment: That's the whole thing right now. I was just testing the Robot class, but I noticed this and stripped it down to the essential in order to demonstrate the issue. There's nothing else in the program.

Comment: It's been a while since I used a java Timer. Do timers die when main finishes? I know normal threads don't in java, but I can't remember about timers. If that's the case you just need to add a while (t.isRunning()); to the main function

Edit: On a second look, you'd have to set a variable to the instance of the TimerTest you created and check to see if its timer is still running within the loop, or just create an infinite loop inside main if that works for what you want.

Comment: Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html).

Comment: As an aside, why exactly are you creating the timer without any GUI elements?  Is this for repeated screen-shots?

Comment: Ok, so if I understood this correctly, the Swing Timer doesn't prevent the application from terminating because it's intended for use with Swing and AWT components, which do prevent that from happening. The while loop did keep both the application and the timer running properly, although there might be better methods to achieve this.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I just wanted the robot to fire key events indefinitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main is processed so the program stops. You can test it by using this code,  adding it to TimerTest()

```
JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
testFrame.setVisible(true);
testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
```

That JFrame keeps your main not from finshing, when you close the Frame the TimerTest ends. Which concludes your main which causes the main to finsh. Ending the program and stoping your swing timer.

Comment: Thanks, this proved very helpful to understand why this happens. So, the Timer uses a daemon thread, but that doesn't prevent the application from terminating, right?

Answer (score 2):

See ["main exits before javax.swing.Timer's start() can start"](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=4169ccba0157122fe47e050b4330?bug_id=6792511) at the bug database.

---

#### Evaluation

Described behavior - when application exits before Swing timer is started - is correct. Here is what's going then:

1. Swing timer is created.
2. Separate thread for swing timer is started. It will notify attached actionListeners when the timeout is passed by posting an instance of InvocationEvent to EDT.
3. Main thread exits.
4. At this moment there is *no non-daemon threads running* in JVM. Application is terminated.

> ..the evaluator goes on to add..

..This looks like a RFE rather than a defect.

---

One surefire way to make it behave is to create a GUI element and display it.  Which is why I asked earlier..

> ..why exactly are you creating the timer without any GUI elements? Is this for repeated screen-shots?

To handle that situation, I would typically create and show a frame to allow the user to configure the rate and area for screenshots, then ***minimize*** the frame and begin processing when the user clicks:

<kbd>Screen Capture!</kbd>